# Why does it say (deleted) on my close vote summary for nondeleted posts?

Tags: support, profile-page, vote-to-close

I just took a look at my recent close votes and saw this:

[image]

Underneath each of my *closure* votes it says `(deleted)`. In reality, only the questions shown with a red background have been deleted. To what does this `deleted` refer? My vote? The question? I tried hovering for a tooltip, but there wasn't one.

Comment: I believe it means the vote was deleted once the post was closed.  I think there is another post about this, looking...

Comment: @bluefeet no need to look anymore, in case you're still looking, I've found it. (was tagged as [tag:bug], not support)

Comment: ah thanks @ShadowWizard I knew it was somewhere, I was looking on MSO.